# Rails Posts relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The code of my project is below:

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :signed_out_user
def index
end

def create
   @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
if @post.save
  flash[:success] = "Post created!"
  redirect_to root_url
else
  render 'welcome/home'
end
end

def destroy
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:content, :title)
end
end
```

**welcome_controller.rb:**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  layout "application"
  def index
  end

  def about
  end

  def home
    @post = current_user.posts.build if signed_in?
  end   
end
```

user_controller.rb

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
 .
 .
 .
   def show
     @user=User.find(params[:id])
     @posts = @user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
   end
 .
 .
 .
 end
```

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_create :create_remember_token
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence:   true,
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

def User.new_remember_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def User.encrypt(token)
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end

private

def create_remember_token
  self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
end
end
```

**post.rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :id
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 85 }
end
```

This code allows creating posts with a title and displaying it on user show action (like Twitter, Michael Hartl guide). **Q:** How i should modify this, that besides displaying post on user profile, it also create a new page with same post contnent,that could be commented,shared or onother action (only in created page!not user profile). After all, **Q:** how to display ALL USERS' posts on main page, I'm trying to do next:

**welcome_controller.rb:**

```
 class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  layout "application"
  def index
  end
  def about
  end
  def home
   @post = current_user.posts.build if signed_in?
   @articles = User.all.posts.paginate(page: params[:page])   
  end   
 end
```

**_post.html.erb:**

```
  <li>
   <span class="article"><%= post.title %></span>
   <span class="content"><%= post.content %></span>
   <span class="timestamp">
  <div id="info">
  <p>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %></p>
  </div>
  </span>
  </li>
```

**home.html.erb:**

```
   .
   .
   .
  <div id="articles">
  <%= render @post %>
  </div>
   .
   .
   .
```

but I've got the following error:

```
NoMethodError in WelcomeController#home
undefined method `posts' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:0x4d151d8>
```

To increase intelligibility of my description, I'm attach the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUCnL.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do posts of all users, so this:

```
@articles = User.all.posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

won't work. Given this is not a polymorphic association, you should be able to just do:

```
@articles = Post.all.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Comment: that was realy so close,i was puzzled around 3 hours,thank you